# Spring Social Facebook Profile URL incorrect

Tags: java, spring, facebook-graph-api, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I configured spring social for facebook and also the spring social authentication in my application with a custom `UsersConnectionRepository` and `ConnectionRepository`.

**Configuration file**

```
@Configuration
public class SocialConfig extends SocialConfigurerAdapter{
    ...    
    @Override
    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator factoryLocator) {
        SecUsersConnectionRepository repository = new SecUsersConnectionRepository(factoryLocator, userRepository, userConnectionRepository);
        return repository;
    }
    ...
}
```

**Connection Repository implementation**

```
public class SecConnectionRepository implements ConnectionRepository {
    ...
 @Override
    public void addConnection(Connection<?> connection) {
        UserConnection userConnection = userRepository.findConnectionBy(user, connection.getKey().getProviderId(), connection.getKey().getProviderUserId());
        if (userConnection == null) {
            ...
            userConnection.setProviderId(data.getProviderId());
            userConnection.setProviderUserId(data.getProviderUserId());
            userConnection.setDisplayName(data.getDisplayName());
            userConnection.setProfileUrl(data.getProfileUrl());
            userConnection.setImageUrl(data.getImageUrl());
            ...
        } else {
            throw new DuplicateConnectionException(connection.getKey());
        }
    }
```

When I add my facebook login, the `Connect<A>` interface object fetch the `profileUrl`, But the URL is in this format

`https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&_rdr`

If I open up this link the browser is says

[image]

**Gradle file**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
        ... }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.3.RELEASE")
    }
}
apply plugin: 'java'
...
jar {...}
repositories {
    ...
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release" } 
}
dependencies {
    ...
    compile("org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook")
    compile("org.springframework.social:spring-social-security")
    ... }
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {...}
```

*What am I doing wrong here?*

**SOLUTION**

updating the FB libary in spring solved the issue.

```
compile("org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook:2.0.1.RELEASE")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you're using the most recent version of Spring Social. The profileUrl should nowadays have the scheme

```
https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/{app_scoped_user_id}/
```

where `{app_scoped_user_id}` is the actual app-scoped user id.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You are right my FB library in social is `1.1.1.RELEASE`.  By default spring boot latest (1.2.3.RELEASE) is including the older version of the social library. :/

Comment: I want to say that, this new URL format actually requires you to log into facebook to view the target profile. While for those who are searching for a public profile URL that doesn`t require log in, it`s still the old formats like https://www.facebook.com/JohnDoe or https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=24353623